# How to select values from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the row where all of the user inputs are equivalent but I'm trying to get values from multiple tables.

```
$query=
"SELECT * 
 FROM (client OR agent OR admin) 
 WHERE (first='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_SESSION['first'])."' 
    AND last='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_SESSION['last'])."' 
    AND password='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_SESSION['pass'])."')";
```

is there any way to do this?

Comment: For starters, use prepared statements instead of `real_escape_string()`.

Comment: Please show sample data and expected result. Do you expect to find either a client or an agent or an admin with the login data and want to show that? Do all three tables have the same columns? Which columns do you want to select?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$first = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_SESSION['first']);
$last = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_SESSION['last']);
$password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_SESSION['pass']);

$query=
"SELECT *
 FROM client, agent, admin
 WHERE (client.first = '$fist' AND client.last = '$last' AND client.password = '$password')
 OR (agent.first = '$fist' AND agent.last = '$last' AND agent.password = '$password')
 OR (admin.first = '$fist' AND admin.last = '$last' AND admin.password = '$password')";
```

This is the way how you could get data, but now you must check in what table data exists and for that you can use [mysqli_fetch_field](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php).

Btw, consider option to reorganize database tables, because clients, agents and admin can be stored in one table `users` with column `type` or `role` which represents client, agent or admin. This method is called [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). After that your queries and data fetching will be much simpler and faster.